# how to solve flutter formstate method?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dart-null-safety

I have this class in flutter

```
abstract class ForgetPasswordController extends GetxController {
  checkemail(); 
}

class ForgetPasswordControllerImp extends ForgetPasswordController {
  
  CheckEmailData checkEmailData  = CheckEmailData(Get.find()) ; 

  GlobalKey<FormState> formstate = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  StatusRequest? statusRequest = StatusRequest.none ;
  

   late TextEditingController email;

  @override
  checkemail() async  {
    if (formstate.currentState!.validate()){
       statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading; 
      update() ; 
      var response = await checkEmailData.postdata(email.text);
      print("=============================== Controller $response ");
      statusRequest = handlingData(response);
      if (StatusRequest.success == statusRequest) {
        if (response['status'] == "success") {
          // data.addAll(response['data']);
          Get.offNamed(AppRoute.verfiyCode , arguments: {
            "email" : email.text
          });
        } else {
          Get.defaultDialog(title: "ُWarning" , middleText: "Email Not Found"); 
          statusRequest = StatusRequest.failure;
        }
      }
      update();
    }
  }

 
  @override
  void onInit() {
    
    email = TextEditingController();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    email.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

but when try this method on emulator i have error message in console says :
E/flutter ( 7876): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 7876): #0      ForgetPasswordControllerImp.checkemail
package:powerecommerce/…/forgetpassword/forgetpassword_controller.dart:27
E/flutter ( 7876): #1      ForgetPassword.build..

Im just a beginner and idk how i can solve this problem

I tried to see if there is any problem with php api files but all files are correct!
and i researched for all the basic problem solving and the same problem exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, I guess it is coming while using `!`. here

```dart
 checkemail() async  {
    if (formstate.currentState!.validate()){
       statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading;
```

You can do null check or just provide default value as false on null case like

```dart
 checkemail() async  {
    final isValided  = formstate.currentState?.validate()??false;
    if (isValided){
       statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading;
```

Comment: this method is works thank you !
but i have the same problem with typing new password page :
goToResetPassword(verifycode) async {
    statusRequest = StatusRequest.loading;
    update();
    var response = await verifyCodeForgetPasswordData.postData(email!, verifycode);
    statusRequest = handlingData(response);
    if (StatusRequest.success == statusRequest) {
      if (response['status'] == "success") {
        Get.offNamed(AppRoute.resetPassword , arguments: {
          "email" : email
        });

Comment: can be issue on `(email!`, try `verifyCodeForgetPasswordData.postData(email??"got null email"`

Comment: i will post it in another topic thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your `email` is not initialized before using it.

Instead `late TextEditingController email;`,

try changing it to
`TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();`